# Read file and send contents via Email using Spring Integration

Tags: spring, configuration, spring-integration

I'm new to Spring Integration and I'm looking to read the contents of a file and use that as the body/text of an email. This is using a recent version of Spring (unsure of exact ver. no.). Note that I'm only going to be using Spring XML configuration files based on what's available in the Spring libraries and classes themselves

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesReader"
                                  directory="file:/C:/data/inputDirectory"
                                  filename-pattern="*.txt"
                                  channel="filesIn"
                                  prevent-duplicates="true">

    <int:poller id="poller" fixed-delay="1000" max-messages-per-poll="1" />
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<!-- convert contents to string --> 
<file:file-to-string-transformer input-channel="filesIn" output-channel="outputContent" delete-files="true"/>

<!-- output content to a file so the payload can be read by the logger -->
<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesOut" directory="file:/C:/data/outputDirectory" channel="outputContent"/>

<int:channel id="outputContent">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="LoggingChannel" />
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="LoggingChannel" />
<int:service-activator input-channel="LoggingChannel" expression="@LOG.trace('LOG Payload is: {} ', payload)" />

<bean id="LOG" class="SafeLoggerFactory" factory-method="getLogger">
    <constructor-arg value="integrationEmailLogger"/>
</bean> 

<int:channel id="mailMessageChannel"/>

<int:header-enricher input-channel="outputContent" output-channel="mailMessageChannel">
    <int:header name="mail_from" value="${email}"/>
    <int:header name="mail_subject" value="Subject goes here"/>
    <int:header name="mail_to" value="${email}"/>
</int:header-enricher>

<mail:outbound-channel-adapter channel="mailMessageChannel" mail-sender="mailSender">
    <mail:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
            <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="payload.length"/>
            <property name="onFailureExpression" value="payload.length"/>
        </bean>
    </mail:request-handler-advice-chain>
</mail:outbound-channel-adapter>

<!--<int:channel id="outboundMailChannel" />
<int:transformer method="transformToMimeMessage" input-channel="outputContent" output-channel="outboundMailChannel"/>

<mail:outbound-channel-adapter mail-sender="mailSender" channel="outboundMailChannel">
    <mail:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <int:retry-advice max-attempts="5">
            <int:fixed-back-off interval="10000"/>
        </int:retry-advice>
    </mail:request-handler-advice-chain>
</mail:outbound-channel-adapter>-->

<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
    <property name="port" value="587"/>
    <property name="protocol" value="smtp"/>
    <property name="username" value="${email}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.required">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I can get the content of the file to print out to a Log file, but no emails seem to be being sent from my gmail account. Any pointers would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see so far that you have an `outputContent` as `DirectChannel` and this one has two subscribers: `<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesOut"`> and `<int:header-enricher`.

By default a `DirectChannel` applies *round-robin* message dispatching for its subscribers. So, the first message goes to the first subscriber, second to second, and the third to first again.

Please, consider not to use that `int-file:outbound-channel-adapter`: you have just read the file by the `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter`. Plus I see you delete it after reading. So, what is the point to write it back to some other directory if your goal is to send email?

Comment: Hi Artem, thanks for the explanation. I was using the ```<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesOut">``` as part of my development process, you're right in that it's no longer needed as I've moved on from reading the contents of the file to making the contents part of the email.

Having removed the first subscription I am now able to receive an email and the body contains the content of the file :)

Comment: Well you do `file:file-to-string-transformer` and `MailSendingMessageHandler` can create a `MimeMessage` with that content: `mimeMessage.setContent(message.getPayload(), contentType);` . So, not sure what is problem. You can scan your logs for email objects to investigate what happens with content. As long as I see you have `mail.debug=true`

Comment: Hi Artem, Yea everything works as intended. Do you know if there's a way to read contents of a file and construct an email from it, e.g. if the file contains ```to:xxx@gmail.com,subject:Subject goes here,body: all of the rest of the email``` to then use the value after to: to be substituted in the mail_to value?

Comment: Well, you need to parse that content by yourself into some `Map` and use that logic from `content-enricher`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/message-transformation.html#payload-enricher